# GCP Cloudbuild Push new Tag trigger doesn't start on git tag created in gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-build

As the title suggest, I setup a gcp cloud build trigger on "push new tag" event.
The repository exist in gitlab and host connection is properly established.

However on creating a new tag in gitlab repo, it doesn't starts the trigger,  though regex rule is able to detect new created tag, so regex is not the issue.

How do I know why cloudbuild trigger is not started?

Note: I tested same repo/codebase through github and on creating a new tag in github, cloudbuild trigger starts

Now its not clear why cloud build trigger for gitlab tag is not starting.
Any help/pointers to debug this issue is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot why your GCP Cloud Build trigger isn't starting for a new GitLab repository tag try these following steps:

1. Confirm trigger is enabled on Cloud Build Triggers page.
2. Verify accuracy of regex rule for tag matching.
3. Ensure user/service account has GitLab access permissions.
4. Check Cloud Build logs for errors.

Note:

- Triggers work with remote origin pushes only.
- A delay may occur before trigger activation.

References:

- [Build trigger creation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#before_you_begin)
- [Cloud Build docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/)
- [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)